# $\ell$-adic cohomology and finiteness of the $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$-vector space

Tags: reference-request, l-adic-sheaves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $K$. Fix $\ell \neq \mathrm{char}(K)$. I'm looking for references describing how the absolute Galois group $G_k$ acts on $H_{et}^i(X \times_K \bar{K}, \mathbf{Z}/\ell^n \mathbf{Z})$ and how are constructed the $\ell$-adic cohomology

$$ H^n_\ell(X) = \varprojlim_n H^n_{et} (X \times_K \bar{K}, \mathbf{Z}/\ell^n \mathbf{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}_\ell} \mathbf{Q}_\ell $$

and how to show that it is finite as a $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$. (I know the basics of étale cohomology, and want to understand this as an example of $\ell$-adic Galois representation)

For now I have checked in SGA 4.5, SGA 5 and the chapter in Tamme's book Etale Cohomology, but i think it's a little too hard for me at the time. (well, to general, I just want that result). I've also studied Milne's notes, but this fact is not detailed enough. Maybe it is in his book ? I haven't found where yet.

Comment: You seem to have 3 questions 1) How the absolute Galois group acts on étale cohomology, 2) how the $\ell$-adic étale cohomology groups are constructed, and 3) why these groups are finite-dimensional vector spaces. I'm confused by the first two questions. For the second: Haven't you just written the construction? What part are you confused by? For the first: Are you asking how to construct the Galois action, or asking to give an informal description of it? It is hard to describe in general but possible in many special cases of interest.

Comment: For the first: how to construct the Galois action, and for the second, well, I've seen this identity here and there, and apparently it's classical and "well-known" how such an object arises and why it is finite-dimensional. If I had to rephrase my question, it would be: "what is a good reference to learn l-adic cohomology, in a more detailed way than Milne's Lectures and easier than SGA?"

Comment: Another pretty standard reference is the book *Étale cohomology and the Weil conjectures* by Freitag and Kiehl, §I.12. It is pretty detailed about the $\ell$-adic construction (at least integrally ― the passage from $\mathbf Z_\ell$ to $\mathbf Q_\ell$ is done with less detail but is also less difficult). A modern alternative is to use the pro-étale site of Bhatt and Scholze, where you can just take the actual cohomology of the sheaf $\mathbf Q_\ell$ (somehow the limit stuff is subsumed into the site).